# Number of permutations differing in at least $d$ spots in pairwise comparisons

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, permutations, recreational-mathematics

A friend and I were thinking about this problem today but we were unable to come up with a solution.

> **Problem:**
>
> Consider the the numbers $S=\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Given
>   $2\le d \le n$ what is the maximal number of permutations
>   $p(d)$ of $S$ you can choose such that the following holds: Whenever
>   you compare two chosen permutations, they differ in at least $d$
>   spots?

Note that we always have $2\le d\le n$ since two permutations cannot differ in exactly one spot.

Note also that $n\le p(d)\le n!$ for all $d:$ $p$ is non-increasing and for $d=n$ one can choose the natural order first and proceed cyclically by writing 
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & \ldots & n-1 & n \\
2 & 3 & \ldots & n   & 1 \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
n & 1 & \ldots & n-2 & n-1 \\
\end{matrix}
so that $p(n) \ge n.$ Actually $p(n)=n$ since when writing the $n$ permutations differing in $n$ spots in pairwise comparisons into the rows of a matrix, the first column will contain all $n$ numbers. Thus it is not possible to add a row to the matrix that differs from all previous rows at the first index.

**Example:** for $n=3$ all possible permutations are:
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 3 & 2\\
2 & 1 & 3\\
2 & 3 & 1\\
3 & 1 & 2\\
3 & 2 & 1
\end{matrix}
For $d=3$ we get $p(d) = 3$ since $n=3,$ by the reasoning outlines above, and for $d=2$ we get $p(d) = 6$ since all distinct permutations differ in at least two spots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for size of permutation code with Hamming distance. I have found a two years old survey of it - http://www.math.uvic.ca/~dukes/pc-talk.pdf. Most problems are open - for example, even sizes for $n = 7, d = 4$ and $n = 7, d = 5$ are unknown.

Comment: Do you understand why slide 44 says "***Theorem** $M(n,4) = (n-1)!$*" when the penultimate slide says $343 \le M(7, 4) \le 535$?

Comment: I suspect it's a typo and should be $M(n, 4) \leqslant (n - 1)!$, as the "proof idea" speaks about upper bound, and then there is a better bound $\frac{n!}{n+2}$ for square $n$.